# Tensorflow, probability of predicted value?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can I get the probability of predicted value?

I can get an accuracy of my data but would like somehow to grab probability of each single predicted value.

My code:

```
    training_data = np.vstack(training_data)
    training_target = np.vstack(training_target)
    test_data = np.vstack(test_data)
    test_target = np.vstack(test_target)

    feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(training_data)
    classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
        n_classes=3,
        model_dir="/tmp/basic09",
        optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
            learning_rate=0.1,
            l1_regularization_strength=0.001
        )
    )

    def input_fn_train():
        x = tf.constant(training_data)
        y = tf.constant(training_target)
        return x, y

    def input_fn_test():
        x = tf.constant(test_data)
        y = tf.constant(test_target)
        return x, y

    def new_tests():
        return np.array(
            [
                [33.33, 44.44],
            ], dtype=np.float32)

    classifier.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=200)
    score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn_test, steps=1)
    score_accuracy = score["accuracy"]
    score_loss = score["loss"]

    print("Score: ", score)
    print("Accuracy: ", score_accuracy)
    print("Loss: ", score_loss)

    predictions = list(classifier.predict_classes(input_fn=new_tests))
    print("Predictions: {}".format(predictions))
```

So, I would like to see a probability of each single prediction in percentage, not sure if it is possible or not?

Any other comment, advice is more than welcome, I am new at Tensorflow and ML.

Thank you.

Comment: please share the rest of the code. What is 'classifier'?

Comment: @gidim, well you have all the code, it is DNN classifier. I have resolved it.

Answer (score 8):

I will answer my own question, maybe someone will find it useful

So, I need to use function predict_proba, that will return an array of values that contains probability.

```
    training_data = np.vstack(training_data)
    training_target = np.vstack(training_target)
    test_data = np.vstack(test_data)
    test_target = np.vstack(test_target)

    feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(training_data)
    classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
        n_classes=3,
        model_dir="/tmp/basic09",
        optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
            learning_rate=0.1,
            l1_regularization_strength=0.001
        )
    )

    def input_fn_train():
        x = tf.constant(training_data)
        y = tf.constant(training_target)
        return x, y

    def input_fn_test():
        x = tf.constant(test_data)
        y = tf.constant(test_target)
        return x, y

    def new_tests():
        return np.array(
            [
                [33.33, 44.44],
            ], dtype=np.float32)

    classifier.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=200)
    score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn_test, steps=1)
    score_accuracy = score["accuracy"]
    score_loss = score["loss"]

    print("Score: ", score)
    print("Accuracy: ", score_accuracy)
    print("Loss: ", score_loss)

    predictions = list(classifier.predict_proba(input_fn=new_tests))
    print("Predictions probability: ", predictions)
```